# Python Pandas DataFrame dealing with datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Python version: 3.3.3
Pandas version: 0.15.1

We have a DataFrame as follows:

```
ID | serverTime
1  | 2015-07-16 02:57:15
2  | 2015-07-16 23:42:20

df.dtypes:
id                            int32
serverTime                    datetime64[ns]
```

We would like to add a column date and hour from this df as follows:

```
df['hour'] = df['serverTime'].apply(lambda x: x.hour)
df['date'] = df['serverTime'].apply(lambda x: x.date())
```

For `ID == 2`, all newly added `hour` and `date` columns return `NaN`. I suspect that the issue with `ID == 2` is that it is stored in a 24h format and that the way I use datetime doesn't work with this format. Essentially I'm struggling to:

- Understand why this is happening
- How to fix it so that the lamba functions do work.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the value for `serverTime` in those rows where you get NaN for the hour and date?

Comment: Doesn't work on these:
2015-07-17 02:13:02 AND
2015-07-16 18:45:09

Did work on these:
2015-07-17 12:44:57 AND
2015-07-16 14:40:19

Comment: I think I have found the issue. Before working on the DataFrame, I did this: df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True). When I changed that to running this: convert_objects(convert_dates=True), it worked. It still remains a bit 'weird' to see that before it did work on some values but not on others

Comment: That will probably mean that for some reason, for some dataframes you don't have the correct datetime64 dtype

Answer (score 0):

try fully qualifying your functions:

```
df['hour'] = df['serverTime'].apply(lambda x: x.datetime.hour)
df['date'] = df['serverTime'].apply(lambda x: x.datetime.date())
```